# F# list folders and files

Tags: list, file, f#, directory, names

I have to write a function called "find" in which I can give as an input an Name. The function has to search files or Folders with that given Name and has to return those in a list.

Here you have an example of what it should look like :

```
find "Hallo" hallo = []
find "Hallo.txt" hallo = [["Hallo.txt"]]
find "Hallo.txt" dokumente = [["Dokumente"; "Hallo.txt"]]
find "Hallo.txt" (Folder ("Test", [hallo; dokumente ])) =
[["Test"; "Hallo.txt"]; ["Test"; "Dokumente"; "Hallo.txt"]]
```

That's what I tried until now :

```
type Node =
    | File   of string * Nat          
    | Folder of string * (Node list)

let rec find (name: string) (root: Node): string list list =
        match root with
        | File (N,G)  ->if N=name then [[N]] else find(name)(root)
        | Folder(N,G) ->if N=name then [[N]] else find(name)(root)
```

Comment: Your example is not very clear. Can you try to explain it differently?

Comment: Why didn't the function you posted work?  What incorrect results did it give?  What is the structure of the objects `hallo` and `documente` in your examples?

Answer (score -1):

```
let find name root =
    let rec loop name node acc =
        [ match node with
          | File (n) -> if n = name then yield List.rev (n::acc)
          | Folder (n, l) -> for x in l do yield! loop name x (n::acc) ]
    loop name root []
```

Comment: Hey, your answer seems to be correct. The only problem here is I forgot to mention that the only built-in functions I can use are List.fold, List.filter, List.map, List.exists. I don't think that I need them anyways, but I'm not sure. 
The function should stay the same I can not change it : 

let rec find (name: string) (root: Node): string list list =